# Thingsboard Telemetry customizations Fail to convert using post processing function in widget

Tags: function, widget, data-processing, thingsboard, telemetry

[cards Widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxTeY.png)

[data post-processing functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87IP.png)

The right cards widget in that picture is the original telemetry and I want to convert to the on/off output like the left side of the cards widget, and it looks easy right. But after several attempts of my codes nothing works well because the output should be like if it's true = On, false = Off. But right now it only show one output which true = on and ignores the other conditions. Maybe someone had these issues and willing to help me figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I figure out that my problems are I send the telemetry in Boolean in Arduino code but received at ThingsBoard in a string, JSON.stringify() is the thing that I missed look in RPC log request. So for those who had the same problems with me may have a look back what kind of datatype that you received etc.